# JAVA. Как обратиться к разным переменным из одного цикла?

Tags: java

Есть 10 невидимых панелей.

```
private JPanel questionPanel1;
private JPanel questionPanel2;
private JPanel questionPanel3;
private JPanel questionPanel4;
private JPanel questionPanel5;
...
```

рандомно выбирается число: n
дальше нужно сделать панели от 1 до n видимыми

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    *['questionLabel' + i].setVisible(true);
    - в джава скрипте видел нечто похожее*
}
```

как это сделать в Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью рефлексии:

```java
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    ((JPanel) MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("questionPanel" + i).get(myClass)).setVisible(true);
```

Примечания:
• i <= n, если n включительно;
• Напишите `get(null)`, если поле статическое, но можно оставить и `get(myClass)`;
• Вместо `MyClass.class` можно написать `myClass.getClass()`.

Comment: Кто, блин, поставил минут этому ответу? Ты, человек, хотя бы объясни, почему!

Answer (score 5):

Можно так

```
ArrayList<JPanel> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(panel);
...
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
   list.get(i);
}
```